# Resizing images via nginx imagefilter vs php gd. Which is better?

Tags: php, nginx, php-gd, imagefilter

I want to know which will consume more cpu resources?
Resizing and serving image live via image_filter module in Nginx
Or
Resizing and serving images live via PHPGD in PHP Script

Since both use GD Library which approach should I use? How much is the difference in performance in percentage?